# In AutoHotKey, how do I block LButton from being sent if it's used in the hotkey context but not if it's used elsewhere?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this script:

```
~LButton & RButton::
    Click Middle
Return
```

Supposedly when I press `LButton` and `RButton` together, they'll work as the `MButton`. This does work but it sends the `LButton` as well. If I remove the `~` from the hotkey prefix, `LButton` stops working altogether.

I've tried various ways to try and make it work.

This does **not** work:

```
#If GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
RButton::
    Click Middle
Return
```

This doesn't work either:

```
middleclicktrigger := False

LButton & RButton::
    middleclicktrigger := True
    Click Middle
    middleclicktrigger := False
Return

~LButton::
    If (middleclicktrigger) {
        BlockInput, Mouse
    }
Return
```

This *supposedly* works but I encountered a problem where I **cannot** hold and drag the `LButton` with normal usage. It works fine with simple left clicking but I need it to work as a normal left mouse button when it's not being used along with the right mouse button in a hotkey combination:

```
middleclicktrigger := False

LButton & RButton::
    middleclicktrigger := True
    Click Middle
    middleclicktrigger := False
Return

LButton::
    IF (!middleclicktrigger) {
        Click down
    }
Return

LButton up::
    IF (!middleclicktrigger) {
        Click up
    }
Return
```

Comment: It is not logically possible to have L&R buttons activate the M button without activating L or R button, while keeping the functionality of the L button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved it in the most convoluted way possible. If you have a cleaner approach to this, please do give it to me because I don't feel comfortable with this but it works so heh.

```
middleclick := False
leftclick := False
rightclick := False

Loop {
    If (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") && GetKeyState("RButton", "P") && !middleclick) {
        middleclick := True
        BlockInput, Mouse
        Click Middle
        SetTimer, middleclickfalse, -1000
    } Else If (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") && !leftclick && !middleclick) {
        leftclick := True
        Click down
    } Else If (GetKeyState("RButton", "P") && !rightclick && !middleclick) {
        rightclick := True
        Click down right
    }

    Sleep, 10
}

middleclickfalse:
    middleclick := False
Return

LButton up::
    If (!middleclick) {
        If (leftclick) {
            Click up
            leftclick := False
        }
    }
Return

RButton up::
    If (!middleclick) {
        If (rightclick) {
            Click up right
            rightclick := False
        }
    }
Return
```

Comment: This sends the LButton down and it keeps holding it down. It appears to work in some applications though.

Answer (score 1):

Someone Stumbling upon this, Read this first.

The one who posted this question was close but...

The concise answer

```
RButton::
if GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
Click Middle
else
Click r
Return
```